# String interpolation does not work with some url

Tags: .net-5, string-interpolation

I don't know how to replicate the problem here... I let you see the problem I have:

I must build an url and I am using string interpolation:

```
var url = $"{_baseAddress}/api​/freightcategories/​{categoryCode}";
```

Here the result:
[image]

As you can see last part of the url is white.... and if I call that url via `HttpClient` I get a 404 error...

I replaced the line above with this line:

```
var url = string.Format("{0}/api​/freightcategories/{1}", _baseAddress, categoryCode);
```

I get this:

[image]

Now if I call the url via `HttpClient` everything works correctly.

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Bas Paap reply on [url in interpolated string breaks syntax coloring](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/url-in-interpolated-string-breaks-syntax-coloring/917731):

> When using an interpolated string that contains an url followed by an
> interpolated value, the syntax highlighting thinks the interpolated
> value is part of the url and formats it as a link, up to and including
> the first parameter.

I guess the url is analyzed this way: When an `http` or `https` sequence is encountered at the beginning of a string, the process of building the url starts, and values are appended to url until there is something unknown, like an interpolated value.

According to your case, `_baseAddress` might be interpolated first, which results in url having the following value: `https://yoururl.whatever/api/freightcategories/​`, which is a valid url and it is formatted properly, and I guess here the formatting stops because the next value is an interpolated one, which is unknown at the moment (`_baseAddress` value is know, but `categoryCode` not yet), so it stops the formatting and when `categoryCode` is appended, is simply does not care about formatting the url further. *(This is how I think it works and it makes sense).*

Here is a quick solution to build an url using string interpolation:

```
var url = "h" + $"{_baseAddress.Substring(1)}/api​/freightcategories/​{categoryCode}";
```

When `h` will meet `ttps://yoururl.whatever/api....`, the `https` is encountered at the beginning and the formatting starts. `_baseAddress` and `categoryCode` values are already a part of second string.

It is their issue and, as far as I know, Microsoft didn't solve it yet.

Also, you can try to specify an `Uri` instance rather that a string when sending a request, something like

```
var uri = new Uri($"{_baseAddress}/api​/freightcategories/​{categoryCode}");

client.GetAsync(uri);
```

Comment: nope... still 404 error.. however is not a proble of color... the url does not work...

Comment: That if I try to use it in my get request in the httpClient I still obtain a 404 error.. it seems wrong...

Comment: It sounds so strange :)

Comment: _so it stops the formatting and when categoryCode is appended, is simply does not care about formatting the url further_ - Are you saying that the string interpolation is trying to determine if a string is a valid url (or uri)? I understand that the IDE has a color highlight bug, but what has that to do with the compiled sources?